# How to set statusCode on Apex RemoteAction?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, apex

I am using [Apex RemoteAction](https://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_js_remoting.htm)

```
Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
    '{!$RemoteAction. SomeTestControllerController.oneRemoteAction}', 
    'someString', 
    function(result, event){
        // Handle ...
    }, 
    {escape: true}
);
```

On the `event` there are `statusCode` inside.

```
{
    'action': "SomeTestControllerController"
    'method': "oneRemoteAction"
    'ref': false
    'result': false
    'status': true
    'statusCode': 200
    'tid': 2
    'type': "rpc"
}
```

How I can set that `statusCode` from Apex code ?

```
@RemoteAction
public static MyDtoObject oneRemoteAction(String Oneparam) {
    // Set the statusCode ...
    return null;
}
```

Comment: you can't directly set it as far i know, but if you throw an unhandled exception (e.g. write Integer x = 0/0;) it would be set to 500

Comment: Sad to hear :-( 
Cause I want to do more then this ...
and the alternate way is only make those statusCode ( and other info ) wrap with the `MyDtoObject `